# laying out buttons in a panel extjs 4

Tags: layout, button, extjs, extjs4, panel

I'm having some serious issues trying to lay out some buttons for my user interface in extjs 4.07 I have a base layout, which I want to change, but everytime I change something one of my buttons dissapears, or one takes up the whole panel, or something else that makes no sense based on the config I've entered. I need help. here's the code:

```
{xtype:'panel',
  columnWidth:.06,
  layout:'vbox',
  items:[
    {xtype:'button', text:'=>', action'moveOver'},
    {xtype:'button', text:'<=', action'moveBack'},
    {xtype:'button', text:'reset', action'reset'}
  ]
}
```

Below is what I have, versus what I want the panel to look like.

What I have:

```
[----------]
[[=>]      ]
[[<=]      ]
[[RS]      ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[----------]
```

What I want, something like this:

```
[----------]
[          ]
[   [=>]   ]
[          ]
[   [<=]   ]
[          ]
[   [RS]   ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[          ]
[----------]
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you take a look at the [VBox Layout](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/layout/vbox.html) example on the Sencha documentation site? It looks like you just want your items center-aligned with some margins between them. Something like this should get you started:

```
layout: {
    type:  "vbox",
    align: "center"
},
defaults: {
    margin: "10 0 0 0"  // Same as CSS (top right bottom left)
},
items: [
    /* Button declarations here */
]
```

Comment: That does it! Thanks a bunch.